# connected sets .disconnected sets in metric spaces

Tags: metric-spaces

let d be the euclidean metric of $\mathbb R^2$

let

**W**={$(x,y):x^2+y^2<4$} $\mathbb U$ {$(x,y):x^2+y^2$ $<4 $ and $x^2+y^2\leq9$}

**X**={$(x,x):x\in \mathbb R$} $\mathbb U$ {$(x,-x):x\in \mathbb R$}

**Y**={$(q,1):q\in \mathbb Q$}

**Z**={$(x,y):(x+2)^2+y^2=4$} $\mathbb U$ {$(x,y):(x-2)^2+y^2<4$}

I have to decide if the above sets are d-connected or d-disconnected.

i'm inclined to say **W** is not connected as its the circle of radius 9 take away the circumference of circle radius 4. so for example i cant get to the origin from a point near edge of big circle.

But to prove this i need to write **W** as union of 2 disjoint sets that are d-closed and d-open.(

to do this according to my book i need to say, as **W** is subset of the reals any closed subset of **W** is intersect of **W** and **F** where **F** is a closed set in $\mathbb R^2$

hopefully ive understood the theory correctly,but now i'm confused how to find my subsets. 
 (im tempted to say the set **$S_{1}$**={$(x,y):x^2+y^2<4$} is open as it is just an open subset of the reals and the set **$S_2$**= {$(x,y):x^2+y^2$ $\leq9 $}-{ $x^2+y^2<4$} is open in **W** because although the edge of the circle of radius of 9 is included in the set, i can put "balls" around these points as there are no points in **W** inside my "balls that go outside the edge of the circle. So **W**=**$S_1$**$\mathbb U$**$S_2$** and this is a disjoint union. is  this anywhere near correct?

i have the same trouble for the other sets. i'm guessing

**X** is connected as its just a cross

**Y** is not connected as i have gaps in the line through y=1 at each irrational

**Z** is connected as it is 2 circles that touch at the origin and the origin is included in the space **Z**

which leads me how do i show it is connected? do i have to show there are no open subsets of **X** whose union is the whole of **X**?

Comment: Use `\cup` ($\cup$) instead of `\mathbb{U}` for union

Comment: Saul :   doesn't that inequality give the boundary of **W**? your comment on **X** suggests it is connected, so how do I know it has no open subsets?

Comment: Saul: can i say that any subset of **X** is going to be union of points (x,x) or (x,-x) but  if then to say these are open i  require a set **S** in $\mathbb R^2$ such that {(x,x)}=**X** n **S**. but such an **S**  must be the point (x,x) along with any of $\mathbb R^2$ not containing **X** and this cannot be open as i cant put a ball around (x,x) as i have no other points on the line contained in X

Comment: @Saulspatz : this refers to my previous comments. just seen I needed to do @ before your name.

Comment: @Mike A : after a search you seem to have followed same course. did you study this module? can you offer any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for **W**?

i have **W**={$(x,y):x^2+y^2<4$} $\mathbb U$ {$(x,y):x^2+y^2$ $<4 $ and $x^2+y^2\leq9$}

so could i let

**S**={$(x,y):x^2+y^2<4$}

**T**={$(x,y):4<x^2+y^2\leq 9$}

so **W**=**S**$\cup$**T** and **S** and **T** are disjoint

now

**S** =  **W** $\mathbb n$ {$(x,y):x^2+y^2<4$}

and {$(x,y):x^2+y^2<4$} is open in $\mathbb R^2$

and can i say

**T**=**W**$\mathbb n${$(x,y):4<x^2+y^2<10$}

and as $\mathbb n${$(x,y):4<x^2+y^2<10$} is open in  $\mathbb R^2$ then

**T** is open in **W**

the conclusion is then since i can write **W** as the union of two disjoint **W** open sets it is therefore disconnected?

im still unsure about the other sets, if someone could even just confirm i have the correct connected/disconnected for **X** ,**Y**, **Z** so i know im in the right area to try and proceed.

thanks

Comment: Isn't $\mathbf W$ supposed to be $\{(x,y)|x^2+y^2<4\}\cup \{(x,y)|4<x^2+y^2<9\}?$ To say $x^2+y^2<4\text{ and } x^2+y^2<9$ is the same as to say $x^2+y^2<4$.

Comment: @Saulspatz , yes I have the inequality around the wrong way. W is just the circle of radius 9 with the circumference of the circle of radius 4 removed. would my answer about suffice?

Comment: Yes, it's correct.

Comment: @Saulspatz , yes I have the inequality around the wrong way. W is just the circle of radius 9 with the circumference of the circle of radius 4 removed. would my answer about suffice?    for X  can I say any subset of it is union of  points,and points are not open so only subsets that are open and closed are empty set and X?   this just leaves Z. I can't,now,even decide if it's connected. I thought at first it is because (0,0) is included in the set but I also have circumference  of a circle so can I write this as intersection of Z with a closed/open  set in $\mathbb R^2$

Comment: @Saulspatz  how do we know the line has no open subsets? in  another question I have to find an open cover of the set $P=\{(x,sin  x):x\in \mathbb R\} $  with respect to the induced metric on  P (induced from euclidean metric). does this not curve not have non open subsets similar to the line case?